# Track clusters over time with kmeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am clustering some data using `sklearn.cluster.Kmeans`. Basically I need to repeat the clustering on a panel of data with $N$ individuals with P features each, recorded T times each, i.e. I have a NT x P panel. I want to perform the clustering at each time t=1,2,3...,T. The issue that I have is that the cluster labels that sklearn gives are not necessarily consistent with the actual cluster if the data change from one period to the other.

Consider the following example (t=1):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
>>> array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
kmeans.cluster_centers_
>>> array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

Scenario A: After clustering data once, I repat clustering at time t=2 on what I call a new matrix of data `X1`:

```
X1 = np.array([[10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],
               [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0]])
```

Notice that this matrix is basically the initial `X` but with reshuffled observations (the last 3 rows now become the first 3 rows). Doing clustering:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X1)
kmeans.labels_
>>> array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

which means that altouhg the clusters are clearly identified by the algorithm, the name is arbitrary, which is expected in a sense as there is no way of saying a priori which one is 0 and which one is 1. Nevertheless, I would like to find a way to track the same clusters over time. Looking at the cluster centers

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [10.,  2.]])
```

I see indeed that they change. Hence, my idea is to use the cluster centers as identifiers for the same cluster over time. Is this a good idea or may there be other issues?
Imagine now the following:
Scenario B: `X1` actually has different values than `X`, nto just simple reshuffling:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X2)
kmeans.labels_
>>> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
kmeans.cluster_centers_
>>>
array([[ 6.46, 10.46],
       [20.  , 70.  ]])
```

It is clear that one of the two clusters has grown as 5 individuals (rows) are assigned to it, but given the "inconsistent" labeling illustrated in Scenario A, how can I tell which one of the two clusters (0 or 1) has actually grown?

Comment: What about meassuring the distance between centers (I think ecludian distance would be good) for each iteration and find the closest to previous one?

Comment: That could definitely be an option. In similar spirit, I initially throught to order the clusters by the value of their centers, such that the one with the biggest would always be  "cluster1", but looking at the distance could be more precise